# Sample softphone got stuck

Tags: voip, pbx

We use [Ozeki VoIP SIP SDK](http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com/p_35-ozeki-voip-sip-sdk-with-freepbx-voip.html) and have been able to register the SIP account on the server. The registration was successful, however when trying to make a call using the sample softphone, by using the keypad and clicking the *Pick up* button we got stuck.

Comment: "by using the keypad and clicking the pick up we got stucked" What do you mean by this? What did the phone do and did the display say anything, because the word stcuked doesn't tell us much.

Answer (score 0):

It may be speaker or microphone media connect problem.
When using OZEKI you can make calls without problem , but if you write an AutoDialer unfortunately OZEKI SDK has a bug and you get memory corrupt or 100%CPU problem.
Please explain what you do when CallStateChanged event is received.